# How to solve recurrence $T(n) \le 2T(n/3) + c\log_3 n$ using substitution method

Tags: recurrence-relation

> Show by induction that any solution to a recurrence of the form
>   $ T(n) \le 2T(n/3) + c\log_3 n $ is $O(n\log_3 n)$.

Hoping someone can help me with the correct solution.  I attempted two ways to get the solution (but I think that they're both incorrect):

### SOLUTION A

\begin{align}
T(n) &\le 2T(n/3) + c \log_3 n \\
&\leq 2[k(n/3)\log_3(n/3)] + c\log_3 n \\
&= (2/3)kn(\log_3 n-1) + c\log_3 n \\
&= (2/3)(kn)\log_3 n \\
&= (2/3)kn + c\log_3n \\
&= [(2/3)kn + c]\log_3n - (2/3)kn
\end{align}

### SOLUTION B

\begin{align}
T(n) &\le 2T(n/3) + c \log_3n \\
&\le 2 [ k(n/3)\log_3(n/3) ] + c \log_3n \\
&= (kn - kn/3)(\log_3n - 1) + c \log_3n \\
&= (kn)\log_3n - (kn/3)\log_3n - kn + c\log_3n \\
&= (kn)\log_3n - (2/3)kn + (c - kn/3)\log_3n
\end{align}

Comment: Why do you think your solutions are wrong? Why do you want to use the substitution method? In either of your solutions, how did you get rid of T after one step? You may want to check out our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) for some guidance.

Comment: You can use MathJax to format your mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens when you use the substitution method, assuming a base case of $T(1) = 0$ and $c=1$:
\begin{align}
T(3^m) &\leq m + 2T(3^{m-1}) \\ &\leq
m + 2(m-1) + 2^2T(3^{m-2}) \\ &\leq
m + 2(m-1) + 2^2(m-2) + 2^3T(3^{m-3}) \\ &\leq \ldots \\ &\leq
m + 2(m-1) + 2^2(m-2) + \cdots + 2^{m-1}(1) + 2^m T(1) \\ &=
m + 2(m-1) + 2^2(m-2) + \cdots + 2^{m-1}(1) \\ &=
m(1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{m-1}) - (2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{m-1}) - (2^2 + \cdots + 2^{m-1}) - \cdots - (2^{m-1}) \\ &=
m(2^m-1) - (2^m-2) - (2^m-2^2) - \cdots - (2^m-2^{m-1}) \\ &=
m(2^m-1) - (m-1)2^m + (2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{m-1}) \\ &=
m(2^m-1) - (m-1)2^m + (2^m-2) \\ &=
2^{m+1}-m-2.
\end{align}
This shows that $T(n) = O(n^{\log_32})$.

Comment: Interesting substitution.  Can you explain, though, how O[n^(log(3)2)] matches O[n*log(3)n], please?

Comment: I should've added:  note that your log in big O is an exponent and the log in my big O is not an exponent, it's part of a product.

Comment: The bound I get is better than what you aim for.

Comment: My substitution is actually not so interesting. Rather, it is standard and routine.

Comment: Agreed - your bound is better.  But I'm stuck with doing what my textbook assignment asked for, so is it possible to get to O[n*log(3)n] ?

Comment: This follows immediately from my bound.

Comment: I don't see how it follows - can you show/explain that?

Comment: Here’s a simpler example. If $c \leq 10$ then $c \leq 20$.

Comment: I understand the concept that a stronger than required bound is better than a weaker bound.  But, again, I have to reach, and prove, the conclusion posed by the published assignment and the published answer.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you know that $T(n) = O(n^{\log_3 2})$, then it immediately follows that $T(n) = O(n \log n)$. There is nothing more to prove.

Comment: Big O is an upper bound.  If n=3, then "n log n" equals 3, and "n^log(3)2" equals 2, and thus "n log n" is the bigger bound, which doesn't follow "n^log(3)2".

Comment: Big O is an asymptotic upper bound. It is definitely the case that $n^{\log_32} = O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Nope, sorry, that's not the case, but I won't take up any more space debating it.  But, thanks, again, for the discussion.

Comment: In fact, it is the case. I agree that there’s no point debating it. I just suggest to compare our credentials and experience.

Comment: Please...I went to one of those schools (I'm quite older than you) and, given that the answer is wrong, the arrogance is embarrassing.

Comment: By the way, if you replace $2T(n/3)$ by $3T(n/3)$ in the original recurrence then the solution does become $\Theta(n\log n)$. In your case the solution is $\Theta(n^{\log_32})$, which is asymptotically smaller. You can get the same results from the master theorem.